# Read large file in php and navigate line by line

Tags: php

I am developing a log file viewer in php that should read 10 lines from the file (say 2 GB ) and when user clicks next then the consequent 10 lines has to be read.
when back button is pressed the last 10 lines has to be printed.

As of now I have implemented file read using fgets (due to size of file) and I trying to figure out how to seek the next 10 and previous 10 lines.

```
if($handle)
{
    $cnt=1;
    while(($buffer=fgets($handle))!==false and $cnt<=10) {
        echo $buffer;
        $cnt++;
    }
    if(feof($handle)) {
        echo "error";
    }

}
```

Comment: I would do this with shell execution `exec()` and use the `tail` function to parse the last 10 lines.

Comment: What are you using for the front end? Web browser?

Comment: yes.web browser- jquery to initiate actions in php backend

Answer (score 0):

The SplFileObject class in PHP does what you want to do.  See:
http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.seek.php

Example code:

```
<?php
// Set $lineNumber to the line that you want to start at
// Remember that the first line in the file is line 0
$lineNumber = 43;
// This sets how many lines you want to grab
$lineCount = 10;

// Open the file
$file = new SplFileObject("logfile.log");

// This seeks to the line that you want to start at
$file->seek($lineNumber);

for($currentLine=0; $currentLine < $lineCount; $currentLine++) {
    echo $file->current();
    $file->next();
}
?>
```

Comment: does this work for large files >2gb?   also, when user clicks next button.. o i need to create the $file object again?

Comment: Should work fine on large files. Since you're calling this from the web, you probably will have to open $file each time unless you want to build some kind of server process to keep the log file open all the time and serve up the 10 lines you're client app is requesting (perhaps via an AJAX call).  That said, you should probably just go with the simple implementation for your purposes (i.e. use SplFileObject to open the file, grab the 10 lines you need, and then echo that back to the user).

Comment: BTW, another approach that I've taken (when I was working on a server appliance project) was to build a backend process that committed the logfile to a database (MySQL in that case), which we could then quickly query to grab date ranges, specific types of message, specific numbers and ranges of log lines, etc.